# Как можно отловить нажатие по флеш банеру на javascript jquery

Tags: jquery, flash

Есть маленький флеш банер на странице

```
  <div class="banner">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ... data="images/MP_banner.swf" >
      <param ....../>
     <img src="images/banner.jpg" .... />
    </object>
  </div>
```

по идее при клике на нем надо открывать большой флеш банер с роликом.
Но для этой цели сделана маленькая картинка. и к ней на jquery подвешена функция на click

```
  <div class="presentation">    <img src="images/presentation.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
```

вот jquery

```
$('.presentation').click(function() {
    $('#flashContent').show().animate();
    $('#page').fadeTo('1000', 0.3);
    return false;
});
```

Как можно избавиться от такой 2й ступени, а открывать ролик при клике на банере прямо?
говорю зарание!

```
$('.banner').mousedown(function() {
  ... НЕ РАБОТАЕТ ...
});
```

Comment: $('.banner object').mousedown(function() {
      ... И ТАК НЕ РАБОТАЕТ? ...
    });

З.Ы. Просто интересуюсь.

Comment: Насколько я знаю - никак, либо вызывать javascript обработчик с флеша.

Comment: нет не пашет

Comment: " вызывать javascript обработчик с флеша" не пашет? xDDD

Comment: Я так понимаю вам [сюда](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Comment: нет не пашет - это я Palmervan ответил.
Тоесть только на стороне флеш решение по другому никак?

Comment: Очевидно что - никак, причиной этому является то что браузер ничего не знает о том что происходит в среде выполнения flash.

А не пашет потому-что вы такой код написали, разве не очевидно?

Я не имею практически никакого опыта flash разработки (читай мизерный) и то знаю что это возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создавать div поверх баннера с его размерами, но тогда flash-объект не сможет обрабатывать события мыши

```
var bannerContainer = $('.banner')[0];
var bannerOverlay = $('<div/>')
    .css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "width": bannerContainer.width(),
        "height": bannerContainer.height()
    })
    .offset(bannerContainer.offset())
    .click(function() { /* ... */ })
    .appendTo('body');
```

Comment: не прокатывает! флеш банеры же они всегда выше блоков. поэтому клик до .banner не доходил. и тут тоже не срабатывает.

Comment: Обязательно должен быть <param value="transparent" name="wmode">. Ну и можно принудительно задать z-index у .banner (например, z-index:1) и у перекрывающего дива (z-index:2). position-absolute + z-index решают все :). Вот у меня рабочий пример: http://shans.su Там среди баннеров иногда крутятся флэхи, а поверх флэхи нужно показывать выпадающий список городов (справа вверху). Работает даже в IE6

Comment: @armenka, не уверен, но попробуйте поставить флэшу wmode opaque или transparent. Ибо по умолчанию он window и всегда выше всех, а transparent можно поверх хтмл-ом накрывать.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('.banner object').mousedown(function(e) {
    ...
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Только тут есть неясные глюки с самим флешом (крайне нежелательно в нем обрабатывать `MouseEvent.*`), а в каких-то броузерах требуется загрузка флеша.

**UPDATE**

Вот сделал пример: [jsbin.com/ovugel/3](http://jsbin.com/ovugel/3), правда с jQuery (вызов `.mousedown`) у меня не завелось почему-то, но разбиратся что за проблемы у jQuery - лень.

**UPDATE 2**

С jQuery какая-то засада, корректно работает только так:

```
$('.banner object').live('mousedown', function(e) {
    ...
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Почему это - ни кто мне не ответил, хотя я специально завел для этого [вопрос №70380](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/70380/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-jquery-mousedown-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-flash-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: "требуется загрузка флеша" 

Можно поинтересоваться - в каком виде?

Comment: Ну .swf файл полностью придет на компьютер (порой они грузятся долго)

Comment: ясно, я так понимаю использовать этот подход не порекомендуете? =)

Comment: Есть 2 ролика 1 в виде банера, он мааааленький и висит в сайдбаре, вот по нему и кликать надо, 2й он большой в виде мини фильма, он пока скрыт, дак вот надо при клике на крошке вызвать большого джона.
сейчас его вызывают при клике на ссылке с надписью смотреть ролик...

Comment: так а заменить маленький банер на html элемент - нельзя?..

Да и  ИМХО, 100%, логичнее, в таком случае, вызывать обработчик из флеша

Comment: Вижу у тебя пашет пример jsbin.com/ovugel/3 - норм, повесил к себе, чтото нифига, мож разница во флеш ролике? вообщем еще потыкаю

Comment: Для информации: в SWF-е нет обработки мыши это просто пустышка заглушка, ее исходный код см.: [gist.github.com/1646661][1]

  [1]:https://gist.github.com/1646661