# Событие jQuery .mousedown для Flash-объектов

Tags: jquery, flash, javascript

Пытаюсь разобраться с взаимодействием JavaScript и Flash объектов.

```
<div class="banner" style="background-color:green"> 
    <object
        id="swf2" width="100%" height="90" style="visibility:visible"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        data="http://megaswf.com/file/1862110.swf"
        allowscriptaccess="always" menu="false">
           <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    </object>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $("#swf2").mousedown(
                function (e) {
                    $("body").append(
                        '<span style="color:green">Mouse down.</span><br />'
                    );
                    // ...
                    return false;
                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>
```

Код не работает, хотя, если прописать `eventHandler` без использования jQuery, то все нормально работает.

Вот пример: [jsbin.com/ajafip](http://jsbin.com/ajafip), там два flash-объекта:

1. Красный работает без использования jQuery;
2. Зеленый работает используя jQuery и собственно с ним проблемы.

P.S. Решение через `$("#swf2").live("click",...)` или `$("#swf2").live("mousedown",...)` - работают и я о них знаю, вопрос именно в том, почему не работает `.mousedown`.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwEVQv ваш пример работает

Answer (score 1):

Функция `live` в статусе deprecated с версии 1.7+

**Рабочий пример**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oboWZp

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '#swf2', function (e) {
  $("body").append('<span style="color:#0F0;">Mouse down.</span><br />');
});
```